# porque funciona al importar cv2 y cv no funciona cuando lo importo

Tags: python, video, opencv, insert

estoy intentando esto

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

#Cargar los dos videos
video1 = cv2.VideoCapture('video1.mov')
video2 = cv2.VideoCapture('video2.mov')

#Guardar las dimensiones del primer video
ancho1 = int(video1.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
alto1 = int(video1.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))

#Guardar las dimensiones del segundo video
ancho2 = int(video2.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
alto2 = int(video2.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))

#El ancho del video final sera el minimo de las dos longitudes horizontales
ancho = int(min(ancho1, ancho2))

#Usar un codec compatible con .avi
fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC(*'XVID')

#Crear el objeto VideoWriter
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 30, (ancho,alto1+alto2))

while(1):
    #En este frame guardaremos la union de los dos videos:
    frame = np.zeros((alto1+alto2,ancho,3), np.uint8)

    #Leer un frame de cada video
    ret1, frame1 = video1.read()
    ret2, frame2 = video2.read()


    #Mirar que ambos frames sean validos (uno de los videos podria ser mas corto que el otro)
    if ret1 and ret2:
        frame[0:alto2,0:ancho] = frame2 #Colocar el frame del primer video en la mitad superior
        frame[alto2:(alto2+alto1),0:ancho] = frame1 #Colocar el frame del segundo video en la mitad inferior
        out.write(frame) #Escribir el nuevo frame
        cv2.imshow('frame',frame) #Mostrarlo en una ventana

    #Si frame1 o frame2 es nulo, salir del programa    
    else:
        break

    #Se puede interrumpir el proceso pulsando 'q'
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

#Si se ha terminado el proceso, limpiar...
video1.release()
video2.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

y presento problemas aquí:

```
ancho1 = int(video1.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
alto1 = int(video1.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
```

porque dice que no reconoce a cv entonces decidi importar a parte en shell cv y no funciona pero importo cv2 y ahi si

Comment: ¿Version de OpenCV? Si usas OpenCV 3 (lo que explicaría el error) si mal no recuerdo es simplemente `cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH` y `cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT`

Comment: ¿porque no lo publicas como respuesta?

Comment: Porque no estoy seguro al no poder probarlo ahora mismo, lo digo solo de memoria, hablo desde el móvil en este momento. Si confirmas que funciona no tengo problema en publicarlo. Saludos.

Comment: ok funciona perfecto FJSevilla muchas gracias por favor publicalo

Comment: ger hecho,  he creado una respuesta con un pequeño enlace de referencia para ilustrar algo el tema. Saludos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si usas OpenCV 3 en adelante el uso del submódulo `cv` quedó en desuso, en su lugar usa simplemente:

```
ancho1 = int(video1.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH ))
alto1 = int(video1.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
```

Podemos encontrar un pequeño ejemplo en la documentación oficial sobre el uso de los métodos `set` y `get` en capturas de vídeo junto a ambas variables en OpenCV 3 en el siguiente enlace:

[Getting Started with Videos](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/dd/d43/tutorial_py_video_display.html)